# Need suggestion with Silverlight video streaming

Tags: silverlight, streaming, video-streaming

I'm building a video streaming web site. I should receive video streams from several clients and I should broadcast that streams to subscribed(to a particular video) clients. Never did streaming before. I have no idea what protocol to use, what kind of software is required on server side and so on.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't cover your requirements for receiving streams from clients, you'd have to do some further research on that.
However for the broadcasting from you to your subscribers, especially seeing as your using Silverlight, you definitly want to have a look at [IIS Smooth Streaming](http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothStreaming) to provide the streaming. It is a free addon to the IIS webserver and provides a stream to the subscriber based on what they can consume (based on bandwidth and computer capabilities).

When it comes to the player for the subscriber to view the stream, you might want to check out the [Microsoft Media Platform](http://smf.codeplex.com/) (formerly known as the Silverlight Media Framework). Which is a prebuilt but fully customizable Silverlight player, which works well with Smooth Streaming.